# This Codeigniter function doesn't account for all accented characters

Tags: php, codeigniter, non-ascii-characters

This is a list of accented characters I have [found here](https://memdir.org/lgla/accented.cfm).

`ÂÃÄÀÁÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ`

I have used the [Codeigniter function](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/text_helper.html) `convert_accented_characters` to convert accented characters to ASCII characters. However, it seems to fail for two characters (**Þ** and **þ**), see output:

`AAAeAAAAECEEEEIIIIDjNOOOOOeOUUUUeYÞssaaaaaeaaeceeeeiiiidjnoooooeouuuueyþy`

How can I [extend this array](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/21898a45f323bb74ef6e5ee8cf21c3397467665b/application/config/foreign_chars.php#L48) to account for these two characters.

Would this change be adequate?

`'/п/Þ/þ' => 'p',` at line 88? I am not familiar with those characters and what language they are from!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add this code

```
'/Þ|þ/' => 'th',
'/п/' => 'p',
```

to the array in file `application/config/foreign_chars.php`

This array is used to define transliteration

`Þ` or `þ` are coming from the  Icelandic alphabets. Are replaced with the digraph `th` in english

`п` is from  Cyrillic alphabet and translate in english as `p`

Comment: I think the syntax is `'/Þ|þ/' => 'th'`. This is the sort of change I was expecting thank you.

Comment: It isn't a slash it's a pipe `|`.

Comment: Perfect, I made a pull request for this change and it was accepted so thank you. :-)